# Injecting React JSX through a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bookmarklet, jsx

How do I convert code like this from a html file into a bookmarklet

```
<script src="JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
<script src="react-0.13.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx;harmony=true" src="foo.js"></script>
```

In the bookmarklet code I have got the js files loading by doing this -

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); 
script.src = 'file:///C:/whatever.js'; 
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

But the JSX file which I load by doing the following doesn't appear to do anything.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/jsx;harmony=true'; 
script.src = 'file:///c:/foo.js'; 
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

It does add the script element but doesn't seem to create the react component. 
I tried putting it in a setTimeout thinking it might be a timing issues, but I have a feeling this has more to do with my lack of understanding of how React and JSXTransformer are detecting and processing the jsx file. Is there something I need to call? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used babel to convert the jsx to plain js as explained here -  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/language-tooling.html